# How to return a list in redux with map operator

Tags: redux

I need to add_Favorite return as items: [] but I just cant do it.
I need to map and then reassign again**
I really need to return it as an array and not an object with the new values

```
import { GET_ITEMS, ADD_FAVORITE, DELETE_FAVORITE } from "./actions";

    const initialState = {
      items: []
    };

    export default function(state = initialState, action) {
      const { type, items, id } = action;

      switch (type) {
        case GET_ITEMS:
          return {
            ...state,
            items
          };
        case ADD_FAVORITE:
        return {items: Object.assign({}, state.items.map(item => {
          if (item.id == id) {
            return { ...item, isFavorite: true}
          }
          return item
        }))}
        case DELETE_FAVORITE:
        return state.items.map(item => {
          if (item.id == id) {
            return { ...item, isFavorite: false}
          }
          return item
        })     
        default: {
          return {
            ...state
          };
        }
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to assign an array into an object, and missing a key in your `DELETE` case. Try this:

```
case ADD_FAVORITE:
    return {
      ...state,
      items: state.items.map(item => {
        if (item.id == id) {
          return { ...item, isFavorite: true};
        }
        return item;
      })
    }
case DELETE_FAVORITE:
    return {
      ...state,
      items: state.items.map(item => {
        if (item.id == id) {
          return { ...item, isFavorite: false};
        }
        return item;
      })
    }
```

Comment: you were right. But right now is only chaging that item with the new value . I want it to persist the new value in all the items that I add to favorite

Comment: Do you mean that you would like to be able to add many favourites at once?